# Disable Selection of Particular rows on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am currently using `setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)` method. In my implementation, it disables all the rows. However what I want is to to disable some rows and not all the rows. Can someone please help me that to accomplish this?

Here is my code

```
if (encounterId == currentencounterId)
{                                      
  getNstTemplates().getTable().setRowSelectionAllowed(true);                    
}                           
else                        
{   
  getNstTemplates().getTable().setRowSelectionAllowed(false);                                 
}
```

Comment: Where're you writing this piece of code? Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a custom [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) into your table that ignores or modifies selection events involving the non-selectable rows.